# What is the meaning of the syntax in the Meteor.method function?

Tags: meteor

Example from https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/security-with-methods

```
Meteor.methods({
  'tasks.insert'(text) {
    check(text, String);

    // Make sure the user is logged in before inserting a task
    if (! this.userId) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
    }
}
```

It looks like the only argument it takes is of type `Object`, built-in in JS. But, the confusing part is that it is using strings to define the names of the functions within that object.

Why can't I just

```
tasksInsert(text) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I'd guess you *could* just call it `tasksInsert`, presumably that's a convention to allow "namespacing" of methods. It's just shorthand for `{ 'tasks.insert': function(text) { ... } }`, see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a string to define the name of a method within the scope of a class or a JS Object is acceptable.

```
j@j-desktop:~$ node
> function 'add'(x, y) {
function 'add'(x, y) {
         ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string

> 'add'(x, y) {
... function 'add'(x, y) {
         ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string

> 'add'(x, y) {
... return x + y;
... }
... 
... ;
... 
> class A {
... 'add'(x, y) {
..... return x + y;
..... }
... 
... }
undefined
> let a = new A();
undefined
> a.add(1, 1);
2
> let obj = {
... 'addTwo'(x) {
..... return x + 2;
..... }
... }
undefined
> obj.addTwo(4);
6
```

Comment: Nice to have tried it out yourself! Make sure you also read the explanation in the linked doc in the question comment.

Answer (score 0):

The `Metor.methods()` defines the server-side methods of your Meteor application.
It is not a simple function calling. With that you are defining which functions are going to be called by the client.

This is a way to your templates interact your dataBase, check, validate and make changes.

You can only call: `Meteor.call('stringName_ofFunction', {params}, (err, result)=>{CallBack});` if you previously defined this `'stringName_ofFunction'` as a function inside a `Meteor.methods();`.

The thing is, as your application gets bigger you can define different files for your serverSide methods, so you can get more organized. You are going to use Meteor.Methods(); to tell Meteor that those functions inside that method are your server side functions to be called by Meteor.call() on the client-side.